# How to disable all controls/clicks in background page when angular material dialog open

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

I'm using the angular material dialog (v7), we have editable cells in the dialog and in the below page as well we have editable cells like text area/text inputs.

When dialog open if I pressed ctrl+z then undo operation working in both dialog and background page as well

How to disable all controls (like ctrl+z) in the background page when the dialog is opened.

for a live example of an issue, please check the last example in the following page
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

Comment: I can reproduce in Chrome 94.0.4606.81 if there is no focus in a field in the dialog. I cannot reproduce in FF 93.0. Using the example at the bottom of the page here: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

Comment: This issue might be related: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13054

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found that this is the default behavior of HTML inputs,

If you undo the last input [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_text) twice then the previous input will automatically get focus.

One way to solve this issue is to make all the previous input `readonly`

```js
openDialog(): void {
  this.readonly = true;
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog);

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
    this.readonly = false;
  });
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    matInput
    [(ngModel)]="name"
    placeholder="What's your name?"
    [readonly]="readonly"
  />
</mat-form-field>
```

[Stackblitz Example Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnfs4q?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts)